# Checking file count returned by getmetadata activity in Azure data factory

Tags: azure, azure-data-factory

How to get how many file names/folder names are returned by `getmetadata` activity in Azure data factory?

I want to get the number of files/folders returned by `getmetadata` activity and on the basis of this count decide which activities will execute..

Anyone have any idea about how can we get this count?

Comment: What have you already tried?

Comment: I was trying something like if files are present i.e if no of childitems is greater than 0 then go to flow A else go-to flow B. For that i have used exists feild list. But i want to check i can do that with the help of childitems field list only. Because whenever we use exist even if blob is missing then also getmetadata activity doesn't fail. So i want to do that with the help of childitems. I took Hint from below answer that suggest to use length function.

Comment: But whenever there are no input files for getmetadata, then next if condition activity gives error saying childitems property doesn't exists do you have any particular solution to handle this error so that even if there are no files and childitems doesn't exist is getmetadatas output then too we will be able to get length as 0.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thanks to those who commented and special thanks to Steve Zhao.

Actually i wanted to check if files present i.e length is greater than 0 then go to flow A else Choose flow B.

I've tried standalone greater and length function in my expression (greater(length(activity('GETFILENAMESFROMBLOB').output.childitems), 0)) to calculate length but when child items are 0 but when i tried this previous activity i.e GETMETADATA doesn't contains childitems array in it's output so my If condition activity gives error that property childitems doesn't exist.

I also tried empty function but the main issue was when there are no input files for getmetadata then we should not expect a childitems array in it's output.

So here is how i have solved the problem, at first i checked if childitems array is present in output of my getmetadata activity, then we'll get the actual count using length function else expression will have to return 0. Below is the expression used for if condition Activity. Please check.

**Expression:**

***@if( contains(activity('GETFILENAMESFROMBLOB').output,'childitems'), length(activity('GETFILENAMESFROMBLOB').output.childitems), equals(2,3))***

Hope this may help you!

Answer (score 1):

Please try something like this:

The screenshots of pipeline:
[image]

- **Setting of Get Metadata1**
  [image]
- **Setting of If Condition1**

> Expression:@greater(length(activity('Get
> Metadata1').output.childItems),100)

[image]

Hope this can help you:).

Comment: I noticed here when get metadata's child items length is 0 then if condition activity gives error saying childitems doesn't exists do we have any way to handle this without having any extra activity??

Comment: maybe you can try something like `@if(empty(activity('Get Metadata1').output.childItems),equals(2,1),greater(length(activity('Get Metadata1').output.childItems),100))`

Comment: Empty function also gave same error! 
But it's your answer man which lead me to right answer i got the answer i am posting it below please check and give some suggestions if needed.
Thank you so much

Answer (score 0):

I have faced a similar situation today. This is how I fixed it.
In the get metadata activity "field list", I have added *child items* and *item type* as arguments.
In this way ,even if there are the zero files in the folder, we can get child items in the output.

Answer (score -1):

Below Code in *IF condition Activities expression* should be suffice for ***filecount > 0*** logic.
**@greater(string(length(activity('Get Metadata1').output.childitems)),'0')**
[image]

Comment: This may cause an error when there are no input files to Getmetadata activity. Because childitems you are using for comparing is maintained as an array of input files. When there will be no input then childitems array will not be created. So here it may encounter an error.   Hope you understand my point.